# How to replace multiple StringProtocol with multiple params

Tags: swift

I have a string:

`var testString: String = "Hello %VARIABLE, I am %VARIABLE"`

I need to implement a method to replace "%VARIABLE" with params:

```
func methodReplace(_ inputString:String, _ of: String, _ with: [String]){
    //how to do it
}
```

And the result will be:

```
var result = methodReplace(testString, "%VARIABLE", ["John", "Marry"])
print(result)
//expected: "Hello John, I am Marry"
```

Thank you for any help from you

Update: I have resolved by myself

```
 func methodReplace(_ inputString:String, _ oldTemplate: String, _ newTemplates: [String]){
    var result:String = inputString
    for item in newTemplates {
        var getRange = result.range(of: oldTemplate)
        result = result.replacingCharaters(in: getRange!, with: item)
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. What have you tried?

Comment: @Sven: Yeah, I have resolved by myself. Could you leave your comment about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own solution has a couple of problems. Since you force-unwrap the range it will crash if there are more replacements in your array than placeholders in your original string. Then you are wasting performance since you start looking for the placeholder at the beginning of the string every time.

A better solution would be to scan the string from beginning to end. If you find the placeholder put everything that was before it into the result string and then the next replacement. If it was the last placeholder you stop and append the rest of the string.

```
var result = ""

var iterator = with.makeIterator()

var searchRange = string.startIndex..<string.endIndex
while let placeholderRange = string.range(of: placeholder, options: [], range: searchRange, locale: nil) {
    guard let replacement = iterator.next() else {
        break
    }

    result.append(contentsOf: string[searchRange.lowerBound..<placeholderRange.lowerBound])
    result.append(contentsOf: replacement)
    searchRange = placeholderRange.upperBound..<searchRange.upperBound
}

result.append(contentsOf: string[searchRange])

return result
```

Comment: You make my day